# what is the meta key when in evil mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

What is the meta key when in emacs evil mode?

I have the leader key defined like this:

```
(require 'evil-leader)
(global-evil-leader-mode)
(evil-leader/set-leader ",")
(evil-leader/set-key
  "." 'eval-buffer
  "," 'projectile-find-file
  "t" 'dired-jump
  "c" 'comment-or-uncomment-region
  "w" 'save-buffer
  "b" 'switch-to-buffer
  "k" 'kill-buffer)
```

But I don't think that there is a direct 1 to 1 mapping between leader-key and meta key.

A lot of the emacs key binding examples use the meta key and I have no idea what it is.

Comment: From the Emacs FAQ: [No Meta key](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/No-Meta-key.html).  The Meta key is completely unrelated to the `evil-leader`.  Please try one of the various Emacs tutorials (including the built-in one: `C-h t`) -- you really should know at least some of the basics about how Emacs works even if you plan to live in `evil`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Emacs FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/No-Meta-key.html):

> On many keyboards, the < Alt > key acts as < Meta >, so try it.
>
> Instead of typing M-a, you can type < ESC >[then] < a > . In fact, Emacs converts
>   M-a internally into < ESC > < a > anyway (depending on the value of
>   meta-prefix-char). Note that you press < Meta > and < a > together, but
>   with , you press < ESC >, release it, and then press < a >